# Python selenium infinite scroll an inside bar

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

Am trying to crawl this [PAGE](https://freshbet.com/en/sportsbook/prematch) so that I can scrape the matches on the page , am using python selenium.
Below is my code

```
url = 'https://freshbet.com/en/sportsbook/prematch'
driver.get(url)

sleep(10)
iframe = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'iframe')[0]
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="prematch-events"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]').click()
sleep(3)
scroll_bar= driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.custom-scrollbar-btn")[2]

scroll = 0
while scroll < 3:  
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;',scroll_bar)
    scroll = scroll +1
    sleep(3)
```

Have tried to run the code but the scrolling function does not work, what can I change in the code to make the middle section of the page to be scrollable

Comment: You are selecting 3rd  `custom-scrollbar-btn` but it should be 4th one, no?

Comment: Even with the 4th nothing happens

Comment: Okay I think I figured it out but I'm not sure about the Selenium part. I got it working by typing `document.getElementsByClassName("match-list")[0].scrollIntoView(true);` in the console. Can you try it out?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked to make the middle section of the page scrollable:

```
length = 0
while True: 
    match_list = wait_find_css_selector(driver,"ul.match-list")
    matches = match_list.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"li")
    new_length = len(matches)
    print(new_length)
    driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementsByClassName("match-name")[{new_length-1}].scrollIntoView(true);')
    sleep(5)

    if length == new_length:
        break
    length = new_length
```